# dynamically change text in cards - Jetpack Compose state

Tags: android, kotlin, multidimensional-array, android-jetpack-compose

New to Compose and struggling hard with more complex state cases.

I cant seem to change the text dynamically in these cards, only set the text manually.  Each button press should change the text in a box, starting left to right, leaving the next boxes empty.

What is wrong here?

UI:

```
val viewModel = HomeViewModel()
val guessArray = viewModel.guessArray


@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        WordGrid()
        Keyboard()
    }
}


@Composable
fun WordGrid() {
    CardRow()
}


@Composable
fun Keyboard() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement     = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
    MyKeyboardButton(text = "A", 35)
    MyKeyboardButton(text = "B", 35)
   }
}

@Composable
fun MyCard(text: String) {
    Card(

        modifier = Modifier
        .padding(4.dp, 8.dp)
        .height(55.dp)
        .aspectRatio(1f),
    backgroundColor = Color.White,
    border = BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Black),
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CardRow() {
    guessArray.forEach { rowCards ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            rowCards.forEach {
                MyCard(it)
            println(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyKeyboardButton(text: String, width: Int) {

    Button(
        onClick = {
            guessArray[viewModel.currentRow][viewModel.column] = text
            viewModel.column += 1
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(width.dp)
            .height(60.dp)
            .padding(0.dp, 2.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = text, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

var currentRow = 0
var guessArray = Array(5) { Array(6) { "" }.toMutableList() }
var column = 0
}
```

The grid is created, but the text is never changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Compose view recompose with the new value, a mutable state should be used.

You're already using it with `remember` in your composable, but it also needs to be used in your view model for properties, which should trigger recomposition.

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var currentRow  = 0
    val guessArray = List(5) { List(6) { "" }.toMutableStateList() }
    var column = 0
}
```

Comment: Even the row and column need to be mutable? that creates the problem in Button: that guessArray indexes are now no longer Ints. Compose is driving me crazy.

Comment: @JoePleavin if you don't use it in the composition, then you don't have to make them mutable states. I didn't get the indices problem, please add more details

Comment: within the MyKeyboardbutton the index of guessArray = text and is raised by one each time.

Comment: @JoePleavin I still didn't get it. Please update your question to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I can reproduce it - right now `HomeScreen` have two extra `}` and `Unresolved reference: weight`, the view model is not used at all, etc.

Comment: should be a little easier now..

Comment: @JoePleavin oh I see now, I forget to remove `remember` - you don't need it with a view model since it's not bind to the view lifecycle. Updated version should work.

Comment: Yeah I thought that didn't make much sense. Essentially I need to change my Arrays to Lists and then make my mutableList a mutableStateList. I need to get used to all these different array types and seems like I'm golden